# parse the html data to array data in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.4

I am trying to parse the html format data into arrays using the a tag classes but i was not able to get the desired format . Below is my data

```
$text ='<div class="result results_links results_links_deep web-result ">
  <div class="links_main links_deep result__body">
    <h2 class="result__title">
      <a rel="nofollow" class="result__a" href="">Text1</a> 
    </h2>
    <a class="result__snippet" href="">Text1</a> 
    <a class="result__url" href="">
    example.com
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="result results_links results_links_deep web-result ">
  <div class="links_main links_deep result__body">
    <h2 class="result__title">
      <a rel="nofollow" class="result__a" href="">text3</a> 
    </h2>
    <a class="result__snippet" href="">text23</a> 
    <a class="result__url" href="">
    text.com
    </a>
  </div>
</div>';
```

I am trying to get the result using below code

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$out = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(" > ", $line);
    $ref = &$out;
    while (count($parts) > 0) {
        if (isset($ref[$parts[0]]) === false) {
            $ref[$parts[0]] = array();
        }
        $ref = &$ref[$parts[0]];
        array_shift($parts);
    }
}
print_r($out);
```

But i need the result exactly like below

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => "Text1"
    1 => "Text1"
    2 => "example.com"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => "text3"
    1 => "text23"
    2 => "text.com"
  ]
]
```

Demo : https://eval.in/746170

Even i was trying dom like below in laravel :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
    $array[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

print_r($array);
```

So how can i use the classes to separate the data as i wanted .Any suggestions please.Thank you .

Comment: You should use [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or XmlReader/XmlParser or DOM parsing classes. Exploding `>` is not reliable.

Comment: even i was trying with that as well but not getting exactly :

Comment: `$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
    $array[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

print_r($array);`

Comment: Your html example doesn't reproduce the structure of your real html content.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : please check the below link with my actual data [https://eval.in/746302] But when i try the same concept removing the \n from the code by using `preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n|'/", ' ', $text);` , its giving me `trying to non object error` .

Comment: `trying to get property of a non object`: Yes the problem comes from this line: `$classes = $div->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue;`. Since there are divs without a class attribute, `$div->attributes->getNamedItem('class')` is NULL and not a DOMAttr instance. Obviously in these cases *(when NULL)*, the `DOMAttr::nodeValue` property isn't available.

Comment: Yeah got you . So can you suggest me any solution for it ?

Comment: @5367683: Yes, a way consists to select only the div nodes you want using the XPATH query language.

Comment: Okay let me try with your answer and check @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137114/discussion-between-5367683-and-casimir-et-hippolyte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to target interesting parts more easily. In order to be more precise, I register a function that checks if a class attribute contains a set of classes:

```
function hasClasses($attrValue, $requiredClasses) {
    $requiredClasses = explode(' ', $requiredClasses);
    $classes = preg_split('~\s+~', $attrValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    return array_diff($requiredClasses, $classes) ? false : true;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($state);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
$xp->registerPhpFunctions('hasClasses');

$mainDivClasses = 'result results_links results_links_deep web-result';
$childDivClasses = 'links_main links_deep result__body';

$divNodeList = $xp->query('//div[php:functionString("hasClasses", @class, "' . $mainDivClasses . '")]
                           /div[php:functionString("hasClasses", @class, "' . $childDivClasses . '")]');

$results = [];
foreach ($divNodeList as $divNode) {
    $results[] = [
        trim($xp->evaluate('string(./h2/a[@class="result__a"])', $divNode)),
        trim($xp->evaluate('string(.//a[@class="result__snippet"])', $divNode)),
        trim($xp->evaluate('string(.//a[@class="result__url"])', $divNode))
    ];
}

print_r($results);
```

---

without registering a function, you can also use the XPath function `contains` in your predicates. It's less precise since it only checks if a substring is in a larger string (and not if a class attribute have a specific class like the `hasClasses` function) but it must be enough:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($state);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$divNodeList = $xp->query('//div[contains(@class, "results_links_deep")]
                                [contains(@class, "web-result")]
                           /div[contains(@class, "links_main")]
                               [contains(@class, "links_deep")]
                               [contains(@class, "result__body")]');

$results = [];
foreach ($divNodeList as $divNode) {
    $results[] = [
        trim($xp->evaluate('string(./h2/a[@class="result__a"])', $divNode)),
        trim($xp->evaluate('string(.//a[@class="result__snippet"])', $divNode)),
        trim($xp->evaluate('string(.//a[@class="result__url"])', $divNode))
    ];
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Wow ..it works . Thank you so much @Casimir et Hippolyte .

Comment: How to call the `hasClasses` function inside in `registerPhpFunctions` in laravel ? I m getting the error like this `DOMXPath::query(): Unable to call handler hasClasses()` ? In laravel

Comment: I am just trying to pass the function like this `$xp->query('//div[php:functionString('.$this->hasClasses($attrValue,$mainDivClasses).')]
                               /div[php:functionString('.$this->hasClasses($attrValue,$childDivClasses).')]');`  Then it started giving me another error `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 68719476720 bytes)`. Any suggestions ? @Casimir

Comment: can you please help me out i m stuck at this part . ?

Comment: @5367683: I don't know what is the context, but it is possible to use static methods with `DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions`. Something like `$xp->registerPhpFunctions('YourClass::staticMethod');` and then you use it the same way in XPath queries: `/div[php:functionString('YourClass::staticMethod', arg1, arg2...)]`.

Comment: : Here what does `YourClass` represents is that the function name and what is this `staticMethod ` ?

Comment: @5367683: in the worst case, if can not use `DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions`, remove the function and use the XPath function `contains(@class, 'classname')` in several predicates *(it's less precise but it must be enough)*

Comment: @5367683: `YourClass` is the class where the `hasClasses` method is defined. To be able to use it, the `hasClasses` method must be static, so you have to declare it like this: `public static function hasClasses(...` instead of `function hasClasses(...`

Comment: Tried even that defining function as static . Its giving error like this `DOMXPath::query(): Not allowed to call handler 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::hasClasses()'.`

Comment: @5367683: Did you register the function first using `DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions`?

Comment: Yes i registered the same as you said static method

Comment: @5367683: I added a version that doesn't need to register a function.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, try this and tell me if you need any more help:

```
<?php
$test = <<<EOS
<div class="result results_links results_links_deep web-result ">
  <div class="links_main links_deep result__body">
    <h2 class="result__title">
      <a rel="nofollow" class="result__a" href="">Text1</a>
    </h2>
    <a class="result__snippet" href="">Text1</a>
    <a class="result__url" href="">
    example.com
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="result results_links results_links_deep web-result ">
  <div class="links_main links_deep result__body">
    <h2 class="result__title">
      <a rel="nofollow" class="result__a" href="">text3</a>
    </h2>
    <a class="result__snippet" href="">text23</a>
    <a class="result__url" href="">
    text.com
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
EOS;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($test);

// first extract all the divs with the links_deep class
$divs = [];
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div) {
    $classes = $div->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue;
    if (!$classes) continue;

    $classes = explode(' ', $classes);

    if (in_array('links_main', $classes)) {
        $divs[] = $div;
    }
}

// now iterate through them and retrieve all the links in order
$results = [];
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach ($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $temp[] = $link->nodeValue;
    }
    $results[] = $temp;
}

var_dump($results);
```

Working version - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7ed2615ea32c5b9f0a89e3460da28a2702343f1

Comment: `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 22` I m getting error like this

Comment: Can you post the entire code you're using and which php version? You can see my example working here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7ed2615ea32c5b9f0a89e3460da28a2702343f1

Comment: Do i need to add `<<<EOS` at the top and bottom of html data ? as here i m getting the data dynamically i can not add that . what to do ? i m doing with laravel

Comment: No you don't...that's the heredoc syntax for php strings - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. Can you make sure that the data you're retrieving is correctly formatted as HTML?

Comment: As i m using laravel 5.4 it supports PHP >= 5.6.4 . Any idea why i m getting that error ?

Comment: Make sure that the data you're feeding in is the actual HTML and it's well formatted.

Comment: you can see my data  how i m getting in this link [https://eval.in/746211] . and in html format.

Comment: If it has all those `\n`s in it, you need to remove them. `$newText = str_replace('\n', '', $oldText);`. The single quotes are important!

Comment: Yes . Did the same but `\n` did not go off still some few are there .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137133/discussion-between-5367683-and-motanelu).