# Calling one function inside function in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

My previous question was this [parse the html data to array data in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555739/parse-the-html-data-to-array-data-in-php)

With reference to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555739/parse-the-html-data-to-array-data-in-php?answertab=active#tab-top) , i was trying the same thing to implemented in laravel .Its giving me error like `DOMXPath::query(): Unable to call handler hasClasses()` Then i was using something like below

My laravel code :

```
function hasClasses($attrValue, $requiredClasses)
{
    $requiredClasses = explode(' ', $requiredClasses);
    $classes = preg_split('~\s+~', $attrValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    return array_diff($requiredClasses, $classes) ? false : true;
}


function getScrapedata($keyword = 'laravel')
{
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setHeader('user-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3");
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://duckduckgo.com/?q=' . $keyword);
    $string = $crawler->filter('div#links.results')->html();

    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
    $state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($string);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($state);

    $xp = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    $xp->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
    $xp->registerPhpFunctions('hasClasses');

    $mainDivClasses = 'result results_links results_links_deep web-result';
    $childDivClasses = 'links_main links_deep result__body';

    $divNodeList = $xp->query('//div[php:functionString("' . $this->hasClasses('class', $mainDivClasses) . '")]
                               /div[php:functionString("' . $this->hasClasses('class', $mainDivClasses) . '")]');

    $array_data = [];
    foreach ($divNodeList as $divNode) {
        $array_data[] = [
            trim($xp->evaluate('string(./h2/a[@class="result__a"])', $divNode)),
            trim($xp->evaluate('string(.//a[@class="result__snippet"])', $divNode)),
            trim($xp->evaluate('string(.//a[@class="result__url"])', $divNode)),
        ];
    }

    dd($array_data);
}
```

so then it started giving me another error this `DOMXPath::query(): Unable to call handler ()`

so actual error is here :

```
$divNodeList = $xp->query('//div[php:functionString("'.$this->hasClasses('class',$mainDivClasses).'")]
                               /div[php:functionString("'.$this->hasClasses('class',$mainDivClasses).'")]');
```

Can somebody please help me out with this . How to call the function exactly .?

Comment: Is this inside a class or are the just functions?

Comment: Both are inside same class. @RossWilson

Comment: @RossWilson : did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could get around this is to change your `hasClasses` method to be:

```
static function hasClasses($attrValue, $requiredClasses)
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
$divNodeList = $xp->query('//div[php:functionString("' . static::class . '::hasClasses", @class, "' . $mainDivClasses . '")]
                   /div[php:functionString("' . static::class . '::hasClasses", @class, "' . $childDivClasses . '")]');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `DOMXPath::query(): Not allowed to call handler 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::hasClasses()'.` this is what the error i got

Comment: @5367683 In that case can you add the whole class that those function are in?

Comment: My class name is `HomeController` do i need to add this ?

Comment: @5367683 At this point I don't know what you might need to do...if you wouldn't mind adding the whole class that these functions are inside, and also show how you're calling the `getScrapedata` method/function I should be able to help you :)

Comment: Yeah sorted out the problem . Thank you :)